# Screen time app limit disappears from child's device

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

I set up an app limit for my children in screen time, it was there for a few days, then disappeared. It happened multiple times in the past year. My son doesn't have access to my phone (nor my screen time passcode). My wife is also added to the family as a parent, but she didn't delete either. I couldn't find any logical reason how the limit disappears, is there any way to track it when it changes?

My phone is running on iOS 16.2

Comment: I don't have an answer, sadly, but I'm facing the opposite problem of having app limits re-appear after deleting them. Sometimes multiple times so they end up duplicating themselves. I've had to delete the same one many times, up to three times at the same time.

Comment: It would be nice if apple could properly implement such a simple feature they have had for years. I have similar problems. It’s amazing just how poorly implemented it is.